# How is the _children attribute made invisible in ElementTree.Element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree, attributeerror

How is the `_children` attribute made inaccessible in ElementTree.Element?

```
>>> tr
<Element '{http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001}XMI' at 0x000001BEFA8F40E0>
>>> tr._children
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute '_children'
>>>
```

The attribute appears in the source that resides in the standard library.

```
    def __init__(self, tag, attrib={}, **extra):
        if not isinstance(attrib, dict):
            raise TypeError("attrib must be dict, not %s" % (
                attrib.__class__.__name__,))
        self.tag = tag
        self.attrib = {**attrib, **extra}
        self._children = []
```

Comment: The implementation of ElementTree that is written in C shadows the pure Python implementation. As far as I can tell, the code in ElementTree.py that you refer to is not actually used. The "C accelerator" is imported by default since Python 3.3: https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#xml-etree-elementtree.

Comment: thanks ... assumed it had to be something like that ... sadly i was doing a lot of dodgy stuff with Element in my 2.7 code that is completely broken for what were unknown reasons :)